# Redirect to a route after clicking a button

Tags: laravel, routes

How can I redirect to a route after clicking a button?
What I have done is this, using `url()` . Isn't this dangerous without passing a token?

```
 <a href="{{url('/movies/login')}}">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the helper "route".
Like this:

```
<a href="{{route('ROUTE_NAME')}}">Login</a>
```

And, in your routes.php file, define that route name:

```
Route::get ('/movies/login',['uses'=>'CONTROLLER@METHOD'])->name('ROUTE_NAME');
```

Done! ;)

Answer (score 2):

To redirect to route by it's name, you should use `route()`:

```
<a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
```

And yes, it's safe, since you're not sending any form data here.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf

Comment: Should i use `route()` even if `url()` is working fine?

Comment: @micky using `route()` is a good practice, but `url()` will also work.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to redirect to the login page, then this should be fine, access tokens usually used with RESTful applications (because there is no session); if you are just navigating an user inside your website, then the laravel session handler should do most of it for you,
otherwise

You shouldn't handle login with GET.

Build a form, and POST it to a given route, in which you can validate the input parameters and then redirect to a given url from the server side.

This way you can add hidden inputs with CSRF tokens or other tokens.

Comment: actually the login is using social authentication and `POST` method is not allowed. And can you expalin or share the link about `access tokens usually used with RESTful applications (because there is no session)`